# How to append HTML to a paragraph inside a span?

Tags: jquery, html, append

I am trying to append different liquid syntax to a paragraph tag within a span in order to truncate the content at different points depending on screen size.

Here is what I have currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($(window).width() < 321) {
      $(".alert span p").append("test mobile");
    }
    else {
      $(".alert span p").append("test desktop");
    }
</script>
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="alert">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="larger-12 columns">
        <span class="alertMessage" title="{{ alert_post.title }}"><p></p></span>
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to get this working? Thanks!

Comment: This should work in theory. I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmcH8/) with it working. You can change the width of the windows and test it. Are you including jQuery in your page?

Comment: Thanks, yes I have included jQuery, I actually have another part of the website using this same code, although in that example I am appending the HTML to a div and not a span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a `p` element inside a `span` element, by HTML syntax. Browsers enforce this when you try to nest elements that way in HTML markup. You can produce such element nesting by creating elements in JavaScript, but there would be little point in doing so.

You should start from valid HTML, e.g. using `div` rather than `span` here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've changed the span to a div and it seems to be working now.